# What is the name of this Nintendo Switch accessory?

Tags: nintendo-switch, gaming-accessories, hardware-identification

This accessory is included with every Nintendo Switch that ships.

[image: Nintendo Switch controller adapter thingy]

But we never know what to call it.

Usually in our household we'll be like "can you pass me the grip thingy that the controllers dock into for single-player mode?"

That's getting a bit tiresome. Sure, we could give it our own name ("black handle Playstationy whosamawhatsit") but... I have to believe that the designers of this accessory gave it a name. And that name is probably more accurate and dignified than whatever label we might conceive of.

So, what is this thing called?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The accessory that ships with every Nintendo Switch is called the [**Joy-Con Grip**](https://www.nintendo.com/switch/tech-specs/#grip-section). It's *only* purpose is to hold the Joy-Cons, in case you want to use them as a traditional controller. It *does not* charge the Joy-Cons at all. The Joy-Con Grip ships with every Nintendo Switch console (except the Switch Lite), and cannot be purchased separately.

The **Joy-Con Charging Grip**, meanwhile, is a separate purchase.

You can tell both grips apart by the fact that the Charging Grip is partially transparent:
[image: Comparison picture of the Joy-Con Grip and the Joy-Con Charging Grip]
<sup>Picture taken from [Polygon](https://www.polygon.com/2017/1/16/14285520/nintendo-switch-joy-con-charging-grip)</sup>

Comment: Whilst you can’t buy it separately, there are many third-party clones that look very similar.

Comment: It's also possible to 3d print these as well. Thingiverse has a few.

Comment: We ended up buying a used grip in excellent condition. If you've got 4 Joy-Cons, it's really nice having an additional grip for 2-player games in which you need to be able to navigate 3D space with one thumb stick while looking around with the other. (Minecraft and most LEGO games fall into this category, for example.)

Answer (score 7):

This accessory is simply called **Joy-Con Grip**.

https://www.nintendo.com/switch/buy-now/accessories/